# Can't view my static website, hosted with S3 and Route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm trying to get a static site set up using S3 and Route 53 for DNS. I've never used AWS before and my knowledge of DNS records is elementary.

Here's what I've done:

1. I own the domain metrosndbx.info
2. I've created a hosted zone in Route 53 for this domain
3. I've changed the nameservers for my domain to the nameservers given by Route 53 (I did this more than 48 hours ago)
4. I've added a CNAME record to my hosted zone that points to an S3 bucket: www.metrosndbx.info CNAME http://www.metrosndbx.info.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
5. My S3 bucket is called www.metrosndbx.info and is set up as a website, with a bucket policy that grants public permission according to the FAQ on Amazon's site.

Yet, my browser can't resolve www.metrosndbx.info. Though I can resolve the endpoint of the bucket: http://www.metrosndbx.info.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Any ideas why my CNAME doesn't seem to be working. My knowledge of this is very limited, but a look here (http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3awww.metrosndbx.info) seems to return a CNAME record that looks right to me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CNAME shouldn't contain the protocol. It should be "www.metrosndbx.info.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" and not "http://www.metrosndbx.info.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/".